UART issue in ATmega2560 and Microchip Studio
Using Microchip Studio, I have implemented a code snippet to send a character via UART using ATmega2560 and a USB-to-TTL device.
The code for sending a character is as follows:
void USART0_Init(unsigned int ubrr){
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;

    /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
    UCSR0C |= (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
    
    /* Enable transmitter */
    UCSR0B |= (1<<TXEN0);
}
void USART0_Transmit(char data)
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    
    /* Put data into a buffer and send the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}

The previous code snippet sends a character SUCCESSFULLY to my PC to be seen on a terminal software tool (I am using Docklight), however when attempting to send a whole string using the following function:
void Terminal_SendString(char* str)
{
    unsigned short int chr = 0;
    while(str[chr] != '\0')
    {
        USART0_Transmit(str[chr]);
        ++chr;
    }
}

it gives me a garbage value, to be precise it gives me the decimal value "255" but in its representation in ASCII code.
Despite the simplicity of this issue, it's been more than a whole week in investigating it, with no signs of success !!

How exactly are you calling Terminal_SendString()?  My guess is that the string is in program memory, but the function as written will only work with a string in RAM.

@jasonharper I defined a pointer to a character that points to that string, and then this function is called inside main() with character pointer passed to it as an argument!

@jasonharper Note that the same code works for ATmega328p PERFECTLY, also, the same code works inside the Arduino environment PERFECTLY with ATmega2560, too! IDK what's the problem with Microchip Studio and ATmega2560...

How are you passing down the argument to that function? As an aside, the function should take const char*.

@emacsdrivesmenuts I have tried passing it to a const char*, and still in vain!

You still didn't provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Very likely, you are passing down a wrong / bad pointer value as str.

@emacsdrivesmenuts I will try modifying the pointer and will get back to you!

You set the stop bits to 2-BIts is this still correct? Normally is 8N1 (8Bits/No Parity/1 Stopbit)! If you send this without a delay in your code and the terminal is not set to 2 stopbits it can cause a weired terminal output.

It sounds like the code for sending a single character is working correctly, but sending a string results in garbage values. This issue is likely due to an issue with the string handling in your code.
Here's a step-by-step approach to debug and fix the issue:
Step-by-Step Debugging

Check String Initialization:

Ensure that the string passed to Terminal_SendString is properly null-terminated.


Verify Character Transmission:

Since USART0_Transmit is working for a single character, it's important to verify that each character in the string is being correctly passed to this function.


Add Debug Statements:

Add debug statements or breakpoints to inspect the value of each character before it is transmitted.



Example Debugging and Fixed Code
Here is a modified version of your code with added debug output to help trace the issue:
#include <avr/io.h>

// Function to initialize USART0
void USART0_Init(unsigned int ubrr) {
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;

    /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
    UCSR0C = (1 << USBS0) | (3 << UCSZ00);
    
    /* Enable transmitter */
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0);
}

// Function to transmit a single character
void USART0_Transmit(char data) {
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    
    /* Put data into a buffer and send the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}

// Function to send a string via USART0
void Terminal_SendString(char* str) {
    unsigned short int chr = 0;
    while (str[chr] != '\0') {
        // Debug output to verify each character
        char debug_char = str[chr];
        USART0_Transmit(debug_char);
        ++chr;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Example usage
    unsigned int ubrr = 103; // Example for 9600 baud rate with 16MHz clock
    USART0_Init(ubrr);

    // Example string to send
    char example_str[] = "Hello, World!";
    Terminal_SendString(example_str);

    while (1) {
        // Main loop
    }
}

Points to Verify

Correct Baud Rate:

Make sure the ubrr value is correctly calculated based on your clock frequency and desired baud rate. For a 16MHz clock and 9600 baud, ubrr should be 103.


String Null-Termination:

Ensure the string you pass to Terminal_SendString is properly null-terminated. In C, strings are arrays of characters ending with a null character \0.


Memory Corruption:

Ensure there is no memory corruption or overwriting happening in your code that might alter the string.



Example of Properly Null-Terminated String
char example_str[] = "Hello, World!";

Additional Checks

If you have access to a debugger, place breakpoints in the Terminal_SendString function and inspect the values of str[chr] and debug_char.
Use a simpler string to ensure there are no hidden characters causing issues.

By following these steps, you should be able to identify and fix the issue with sending a string over UART on your ATmega2560.

Presumably, a flash string is being passed down to Terminal_SendString, you cannot test that.
